# Using va_list in imp_implementationWithBlock get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 11

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, ios11

I upgrade my device to iOS 11-beta6, then i found than something problem with runtime code.

```
IMP swizzledImplementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(^BOOL(NSObject *obj, ...) { 
   va_list arguments;
   va_start(arguments, obj);
   id argument = va_arg(arguments, id);
   va_end(arguments);
};
```

When i try to use va_arg to  get the first argument after obj, then the app run into EXC_BAD_ACCESS. but the code is OK on iOS simulator and some devices on ios 10/9/8(It is also crash on some ios 10.2 devices).

Is there any change with va_list? or imp_implementationWithBlock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i find the problem, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38470

> On 64-bit ARM varargs routines use different calling conventions from standard routines, thus implementing a non-varargs method with a varargs block is simply not feasible.